# How to adjust WPF Scrollviewer stick with windows side

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to adjust the scrollviewer stick with windows side ? please refer to the diagrams have a clearer visual. The scrollbar will resize based on windows accordingly.

[image]

```
    <ScrollViewer Height="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Header="A 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                //GroupBox A
                //GroupBox B
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <GroupBox Header="C" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" Width="600">
                        <Grid Margin="5, 0, 5, 0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="105" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="105" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="D" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" Height="25" />

                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="Okay" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" Width="90" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </Grid>
                    </GroupBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Post your XAML code.

Comment: Without looking at your xaml code, nobody would be able to help you out. So please add your xaml code.

Comment: Whatever is wrapping your scrollviewer doesn't have 100% width. Try using a `DockPanel`. Post your XAML for a full answer.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have posted XAML, Thanks for reply

Comment: Take `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` off of your `ScrollViewer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the HorizontalAlignment="Left" from the ScrollViewer in your XAML